# Change variables in swift package

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I have created a swift package which contains UI elements which reference locally stored static colors, the colors are stored in an assets folder and then are accessible with the following:

```
public extension Color {
    static let UI = Color.UIColors()
    
    struct UIColors {
        public let DarkGray = Color("DarkGray")
        public let LightGray = Color("LightGray")
        ...
    }
}
```

Through out my views I just use **Color.UI.DarkGray** to get the defined DarkGray color.

I would now like to create a new application using this same package, but some of the UI controls will need to use different colors. Is changing the variables in the UIColors class to be var instead of let a good solution or is there a better way to configure the variable for a package?